# Why can't I open a .xls with QGIS in OSX?

Tags: qgis, data, osx, excel

I'm trying to open an `.xls`with QGIS 1.8 in a Mac, I'm loading the vector layer from `Add new vector layer`etc. etc. the procedure works in Windows but not in Mac where I have an error `Invalid source file`. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [XY Tools](http://hub.qgis.org/projects/xytools) QGIS plugin to load .XLS files just fine on the Mac. You do, however, need to install some required Python libraries.

Open a Terminal window and enter:

```
sudo easy_install xlrd
```

You'll need to give your admin password, then the `xlrd` Python library will install. Then:

```
sudo easy_install xlwt
```

You can then open an XLS file (but not XLSX it seems) as a point file.

*Tested working on Mac OS X 10.8.5, QGIS 2.0.*

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a missing library.  One workaround would be to open the file in another spreadsheet program like LibreOffice's Calc and save it as a csv or tab delimited text file.  Here's the installation steps for the Mac version of LibreOffice:

https://www.libreoffice.org/get-help/installation/mac/